# Why is the monitoring interface time (TOTAL_TIME) so large when using Spring Boot Actuator to monitor the API of a Java web project?

Tags: jmeter, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

A Spring Boot project has an interface, and the Actuator is used to monitor the number of calls and time for that interface, using the @Timed annotation on a certain request method.

After completing tests with JMeter, where the testing process is far less than 10 minutes, accessing `http://xxx:xxx/actuator/metrics/METRICS_NAME` shows that the TOTAL_TIME parameter is around 2000 seconds, with a COUNT of 40,000.

**The question is: TOTAL_TIME is over 2000 seconds, about 33 minutes, which is much greater than the test process time. Is this normal?**

When I use JMeter for testing, with a small number of threads and loop counts, the time obtained is not particularly large. However, when the number of threads or loop counts is increased, the final value of TOTAL_TIME becomes very large.

Answer (score 0):

[`TOTAL_TIME`](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/16/micrometer-spring-boot-2-s-new-application-metrics-collector) is sum of all response times since application start (or metrics reset)

Instead of comparing it to test duration you should compare it to the sum of elapsed times of all [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers which are in your [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles)

If you want you can calculate the sum of all Samplers response times somewhere in [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) code:

```
def total_time = 0

new File('/path/to/result/file.jtl').withReader { reader ->
    reader.eachLine { line, lineNumber ->
        if (lineNumber > 1) {
            def columns = line.split(',')
            def elapsed = columns[1].toBigDecimal()
            if (elapsed) {
                total_time += elapsed
            }
        }
    }
}
```